# Match string parameter id to controller parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.0 project and I have problem matching this:

```
<a asp-controller="User" asp-action="AddFriend" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Add 
Friend</a>
```

To my method in the UserController:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddFriend(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    User currentUser =  _manager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    User targetUser = _service.GetById(id);

    _service.AddFriend(currentUser, targetUser);

    return RedirectToAction(actionName: nameof(Index), controllerName: "Home");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't even match the method.

Comment: It receives BAD REQUEST - parameterless.

Comment: I'm assuming your `UserController` inherits from `Controller` - how have you configured routing within your app?